How can I remove/disassociate a user in MS Clarity?
I'm setting up Clarity in a NextJS application. Users can log in and out. I call identify once the user logs in. However, I cannot find any reference in the docs on disassociating a user from the session. The Identify API, specifically states that the "custom-id" is mandatory.
